# Python 3 f-string alternative in Python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, f-string

Mostly I work with Python 3. There can I write this:

```
print(f"The answer is {21 + 21}!")
```

Output:

> The answer is 42!

But in Python 2, [f-strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)#Expressions) do not exist. So is the following the best way?

```
print("the answer is " + str(21 + 21) + "!")
```

Comment: `format` exists in 2.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python string formatting: % vs. .format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)

Comment: a = 21 + 21    print("the answer is {}".format(a))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `format`:

`print("the answer is {} !".format(21 + 21))`

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways

```py
>>> "The number is %d" % (21+21)
'The number is 42'
>>> "The number is {}".format(21+21)
'The number is 42'
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can use the [.format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method for readability, and it is the where the f-string comes from.

You can use:

```
print("the answer is {}!".format(21+21))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `fstring` library

`pip install fstring`

```py
>>> from fstring import fstring as f
>>> a = 4
>>> b = 5
>>> f('hello result is {a+b}')
u'hello result is 9'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `simple-fstring` library may be an alternative for you!

### Installation

`pip install simple-fstring`

### Usage

```py
from fstring import f
print f("The answer is ${21 + 21}!")
```

Output:

> The answer is 42!